# My JavaScript code is working , but I have error .

Tags: javascript

Here is the exercise i'm doing : http://www.codecademy.com/courses/building-an-address-book/0/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#

You can see all the requirements in the link , but basicly it wants from me to print the information of the contacts for example we have Bob and Mary

Code I used worked , but It comes out this error "Oops, try again. It looks like your list function didn't console.log "Bob Jones". Did you remember to call list(); after creating it?"

Information about Bob did print out (You can try the code) and I still have the error

Here is my code :

```
    var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

function list(){
        var contactsLength = contacts;
        for(var i; i<contacts.length ; i++){
                printPerson(i);
            }
    }

    console.log(contacts);
```

Comment: So your question is, where is my error?

Comment: there you go, two answers, the question I asked in my comments the other person answered on calling list() , that is good advice on their part.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.

```
 printPerson(i);
```

Change to

```
 printPerson(contacts[i]);
```

Also in your for loop

```
var i;
```

Change to

```
var i = 0;
```

Lastly, who is calling your list function?

Comment: See KarelG's answer on calling list, you don't need the contactLength variable by the way, as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't have initialized the length of your array correctly

```
var contactsLength = contacts;
```

should be

```
var contactsLength = contacts.length;
```

And the

```
printPerson(i);
```

should be

```
printPerson(contacts[i]);
```

i is an integer variable. By using it in `contacts[x]` will get the object on index in array `contacts` .

It will pass the array size to the `contactsLength` field which can be used in the loop.
But to run your code, you have to invoke the `list()` - function at the load.

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    list();
 });
```

Comment: I like your windows listener, the guy does not really need the contactsLength he never uses it :)